Using oauthplayground to get a refreshtoken to send emails
I am using a cloud function in firebase to send an email.
I use a refresh token I get from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground.
Everything works fine for a week. After a week I need to get a new token and then it will last for a new week. How can I solve it to have a permanent solution?
const clientId = '<id>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const clientSecret = '<secret>';
const refreshToken = '<erfresh_token_from_oauthplayground>';        
        
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
            clientId,
            clientSecret,
            'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground',
        );

        oauth2Client.setCredentials({
            refresh_token: refreshToken
        });
const newAccessToken = oauth2Client.getAccessToken()

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: '<gmail_user>@gmail.com',
        clientId: clientId,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        refreshToken: refreshToken,
       accessToken: newAccessToken,
    }
});


exports.sendEmailNotification1 = functions.firestore.document("users_details/{email}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const mailOptions = {
      from: "User <<gmail_user>@gmail.com>",
      to: "<gmail_user>@gmail.com",
      subject: "New Record Added",
      text: "New record added to users_details",
    };

    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });

Thanks in advance,
Nuno

Playground is for development only.   Have you code authorize the user
